# Why am I getting different output in my java program?

Tags: java

Why am I getting different output in my java program ?

> output(what i am getting:)

0.0

0.0

They are equal

> output(what it should be:)

91.95

45.975

78.25 is greater

```java
public class myMain {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
                A v = new A();
                v.set(13.7, 78.25);
                v.add();
                v.half();
                v.max();
        }
    }

    public class A {
        private double D ,E;

        public void set(double d, double e) {
                d=D;
                e=E;
        }

        public void add(){
                System.out.println(D+E);
        }

        public void half(){
                System.out.println((D+E)/2);
        }

        public void max(){
                if(D>E)
                        System.out.println(D+" is greater");
                else if(E>D)
                        System.out.println(E+" is greater");
                else
                        System.out.println("They are equal");
        }
    }
```

What's wrong in the program?

Comment: Assignment is right to left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the wrong way around.  Write this instead

```
D=d;
E=e;
```

The left hand side is the variable you want to change, and the right hand side is the expression you want it to have the result of.

Answer (score 1):

In set method put D=d and E=e.